# One element of a tuple dict-key matching in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

If I have a dict such as:

```
foo = {('foo', 45):5, ('bar', 34):3}
```

How can I check against part of that tuple?

```
if 'foo' in foo: #should be true
    pass
if 45 in foo: #also should be true
```

Or some other syntax.

Comment: PEP8: no spaces after { or before }. No spaces before ':'. I guess you meant ('bar', 34)

Comment: one question: you want to make a lot of these checks? if that's the case, maybe you'll better build a set with 'foo', 45, 'bar', etc. from foo.

Comment: In general dictionaries are not optimised for this; if you require efficiency you should restructure your data so that you don't need to do it.

Comment: This shouldn't have to be a very common check; more of a collision test than anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> foo = {('foo', 45): 5, ('bar', 34): 3}    
>>> any(t1 == "foo" for (t1, t2) in foo)
True    
>>> any(t2 == 45 for (t1, t2) in foo)
True
```

If you don't know where the value is to be found you can just check the whole pair:

```
>>> any(45 in pair for pair in foo)
True
```

You can also a generators approach ([flatten](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes)):

```
>>> 45 in flatten(foo)
True
```

That said, probably the best idea is to build your data so you can check this kind of inclussion in O(1) time (a set? a refactored dictionary?)

Comment: works fine, even if keys are a mix between tuples and not tuples

Answer (score 1):

You can use `operator.concat` to flatten all keys:

```
>>> import operator
>>> 'foo' in reduce(operator.concat, foo.keys())
True
```

...or any:

```
any('foo' in t for t in foo.keys())
```

Comment: Ah too late! tokland has post before me!

Comment: +1 you have a nicer solution, though! (The latter; the former is somewhat overkill.)

Comment: yup, "any" is better than "reduce" because it will break on match.

Comment: And tokland edited in the more general solution before I could post :(

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility using list comprehension:

```
if 'foo' in [key[0] for key in foo]:
  pass
if 45 in [key[1] for key in foo]:
```