# Optimised Python dictionary / negative index storage

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary, indices

<s>Raised by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212668/one-element-of-a-tuple-dict-key-matching-in-python) question's comments</s> (I can see that this is irrelevant), I am now aware that using dictionaries for data that needs to be queried/accessed regularly is not good, speedwise.

I have a situation of something like this:

```
someDict = {}
someDict[(-2, -2)] = something
somedict[(3, -10)] = something else
```

I am storing keys of coordinates to objects that act as arrays of tiles in a game. These are going to be negative at some point, so I can't use a list or some kind of sparse array (I think that's the term?).

Can I either:

- Speed up dictionary lookups, so this would not be an issue
- Find some kind of container that will support sparse, negative indices?

I would use a list, but then the querying would go from O(log n) to O(n) to find the area at (x, y). (I think my timings are off here too).

Comment: `dict`s have no problem with negative keys or negative numbers in tuples for keys. What kind of access patterns are you worried about bad performance?

Comment: It is not the negative key issue I am worrying about; I was told from the previous question that 'In general dictionaries are not optimised for this; if you require efficiency you should restructure your data so that you don't need to do it. '

Comment: I don't think your question is related to the question you link points to unless you want to access e.g. all items whose first index element is a certain value. "Using dictionaries for data that needs to be queried/accessed regularly is not good" is definitely not correct in the general case; in fact, dictionary access is usually constant in time.

Comment: "this" in that comment means "checking against *part* of the index tuple", not "using tuples as keys". For representation of two-dimensional lattices, you can often use "dense" arrays (if the lattice is not too large) or dictionaries.

Comment: I can see how it is irrelevant now, thanks. However, I cannot really edit my original post without it falling into some kind of mess. I shall leave it; my original ideas shall show through, I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary lookups are *very* fast. Searching for part of the key (e.g. all tiles in row x) is what's not fast. You could use a dict of dicts. Rather than a single dict indexed by a 2-tuple, use nested dicts like this:

```
somedict = {0: {}, 1:{}}
somedict[0][-5] = "thingy"
somedict[1][4] = "bing"
```

Then if you want all the tiles in a given "row" it's just `somedict[0]`.

You will need some logic to add the secondary dictionaries where necessary and so on. Hint: check out `getitem()` and `setdefault()` on the standard `dict` type, or possibly the `collections.defaultdict` type.

This approach gives you quick access to all tiles in a given row. It's still slow-ish if you want all the tiles in a given column (though at least you won't need to look through every single cell, just every row). However, if needed, you could get around that by having two dicts of dicts (one in column, row order and the other in row, column order). Updating then becomes twice as much work, which may not matter for a game where most of the tiles are static, but access is very easy in either direction.

If you only need to store numbers and most of your cells will be 0, check out scipy's sparse matrix classes.

Comment: That two-deep dictionary idea does look good. I might refactor to this design; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To start off with

> Speed up dictionary lookups, so this would not be an issue

Dictionary lookups are pretty fast O(1), but (from your other question) you're not relying on the hash-table lookup of the dictionary, your relying on a linear search of the dictionary's keys.

> Find some kind of container that will support sparse, negative indices?

This isn't indexing into the dictionary. A tuple is an immutable object, and you are hashing the tuple as a whole. The dictionary really has no idea of the contents of the keys, just their hash.

I'm going to suggest, as others did, that you restructure your data.

For example, you could create objects that encapsulate the data you need, and arrange them in a binary tree for O(n lg n) searches. You can even go so far as to wrap the entire thing in a class that will give you the nice `if foo in Bar:` syntax your looking for.

You probably need a couple coordinated structures to accomplish what you want. Here's a simplified example using dicts and sets (tweaking user 6502's suggestion a bit).

```
# this will be your dict that holds all the data
matrix = {}
# and each of these will be a dict of sets, pointing to coordinates
cols = {}
rows = {}

def add_data(coord, data)
    matrix[coord] = data
    try:
        cols[coord[0]].add(coord)
    except KeyError:
        # wrap coords in a list to prevent set() from iterating over it
        cols[coord[0]] = set([coord])
    try:
        rows[coord[1]].add(coord)
    except KeyError:
        rows[coord[1]] = set([coord])

# now you can find all coordinates from a row or column quickly
>>> add_data((2, 7), "foo4")
>>> add_data((2, 5), "foo3")
>>> 2 in cols
True
>>> 5 in rows
True
>>> [matrix[coord] for coord in cols[2]]
['foo4', 'foo3']
```

Now just wrap that in a class or a module, and you'll be off, and as always, if it's not fast enough profile and test before you guess.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see it like that regarding the speed. As for your restructuring advice, how would a binary tree work? I get the basic idea of how they work (and I've implemented them before), but how would it work for this? I don't see how I could have a definitive root or tree structure at all.

Comment: I really need a use case, because I'm not exactly sure what you're doing here. You don't need a static root for a tree (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). It also looks like you could use a multidimensional array, but is your problem that you don't know the domain of the coordinates?

Comment: The domain is infinite I think - that is, they can expand until technical limits in every direction. I went away from a multidimensional array because I can't say 'shift everything by 100' because there is no definite negative limit. In the same way, there's no gurantee that the coordinates will be totally contiguous. As for use case, it will be for the storage of NxN tiles in a tile based game.

Comment: I think I can see the binary tree approach, but I don't know how well it would work for searching by the other dimension to what it is sorted by.

Comment: The binary tree was just an example of another data structure. You probably would need to combine a couple structures to do what you want (I'll add another idea).

Answer (score 2):

Python dictionaries are very very fast, and using a tuple of integers is not going to be a problem. However your use case seems that sometimes you need to do a single-coordinate check and doing that traversing all the dict is of course slow.

Instead of doing a linear search you can however speed up the data structure for the access you need using three dictionaries:

```
class Grid(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}  # (i, j) -> data
        self.cols = {}  # i -> set of j
        self.rows = {}  # j -> set of i

    def __getitem__(self, ij):
        return self.data[ij]

    def __setitem__(self, ij, value):
        i, j = ij
        self.data[ij] = value
        try:
            self.cols[i].add(j)
        except KeyError:
            self.cols[i] = set([j])
        try:
            self.rows[j].add(i)
        except KeyError:
            self.rows[j] = add([i])

    def getRow(self, i):
        return [(i, j, data[(i, j)])
                for j in self.cols.get(i, [])]

    def getCol(self, j):
        return [(i, j, data[(i, j)])
                for i in self.rows.get(j, [])]
```

Note that there are many other possible data structures depending on exactly what you are trying to do, how frequent is reading, how frequent is updating, if you query by rectangles, if you look for nearest non-empty cell and so on.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative would be to simply shift the index so it's positive.

E.g. if your indices are contiguous like this:

```
...
-2 -> a
-1 -> c
0 -> d
1 -> e
2 -> f
...
```

Just do something like LookupArray[Index + MinimumIndex], where MinimumIndex is the absolute value of the smallest index you would use.

That way, if your minimum was say, -50, it would map to 0. -20 would map to 30, and so forth.

Edit:

An alternative would be to use a trick with how you use the indices. Define the following key function

```
Key(n) = 2 * n (n >= 0)
Key(n) = -2 * n - 1. (n < 0)
```

This maps all positive keys to the positive even indices, and all negative elements to the positive odd indices. This may not be practical though, since if you add 100 negative keys, you'd have to expand your array by 200.

One other thing to note: If you plan on doing look ups and the number of keys is constant (or very slowly changing), stick with an array. Otherwise, dictionaries aren't bad at all.

Comment: What about if (and this is the case) I have continuously increasing negatives? Wouldn't I then have to shift everything by n each time?

Answer (score 0):

Use multi-dimensional lists -- usually implemented as nested objects. You can easily make this handle negative indices with a little arithmetic. It might use a more memory than a dictionary since *something* has to be put in every possible slot (usually `None` for empty ones), but access will be done via simple indexing lookup rather than hashing as it would with a dictionary.